# Error: [SQL0802] Data conversion or data mapping error, DB2, count query

Tags: sql, db2, mapping, data-conversion

Does anyone know whay the following SQL code would be generating an 802 error?  Could it be because the results of the count query are zero in some cases?

```
CEILING(CAST(round((1 / CAST(
                              (
                              SELECT COUNT(evecas)
                              FROM   evetrn e2
                              WHERE  e2.evesrv IN ('T005',
                                                   'T205')
                              AND    e2.evecnf = 'K'
                              AND    e2.evegrp = e.evegrp
                              AND    e.evestf = e2.evestf
                              AND    e2.evetim = e.evetim
                              AND    lwsys.isodates(e2.evefyr, e2.evefmm, e2.evefdd) 
                                  = lwsys.isodates(e.evefyr, e.evefmm, e.evefdd)
                              AND    evecas !=0
                              AND    evetyp = 'S') AS float)
  ),4) AS float) 
  *1000) /1000
```

The full error being generated in Squirrel:

> ```
> Error: [SQL0802] Data conversion or data mapping error.
> SQLState:  22012
> ErrorCode: -802
> ```

And this warning:

> ErrorCode: 420Warning:   [SQL0420] Character in CAST argument not
> valid. SQLState:  01565 ErrorCode: 420

Comment: Using 1000.0 results in the same error.  I am also getting this warning:  ErrorCode: 420Warning:   [SQL0420] Character in CAST argument not valid.
SQLState:  01565
ErrorCode: 420

Comment: If the subquery returns zero, then division by zero will be attempted (and throw and exception).